# HTML5 History API - не получается сменить url

Tags: javascript, html5-history-api

Ситуация такова: страница открывается по адресу `mydomen/dir1/dir2/page.html`

1) Жмем кнопку 1 и получаем URL `mydomen/dir1/dir2/bbb` как и хотелось

2) Затем жмем кнопку 2 и получаем URL `mydomen/bbb` а хотелось `mydomen/dir1/dir2/bbb/bbb`

Подскажите пожалуйста, как достичь желаемого результата?

```js
function nextPage(curLoc){
        try {
            history.pushState({'page':curLoc,'oldPage':location.pathname.split("/").pop()}, event.target.innerText, curLoc);
            goEndPath = location.pathname.split("/").pop();
            return;
          } catch(e) {}
          location.hash = '#' + curLoc;
      }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="nextPage('bbb')">Кнопка 1</button>
    <button onclick="nextPage('/bbb')">Кнопка 2</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Уберите слеш....

Comment: @AlexeyTen тогда получу снова mydomen/dir1/dir2/bbb
А мне нужен mydomen/dir1/dir2/bbb/bbb

Comment: Тогда напишите bbb/bbb

Comment: @AlexeyTen почему в случае nextPage('bbb') браузер сохраняет директории, а в случае с nextPage('/bbb') сбрасывает.
Кроме того, bbb/bbb это частный случай, эти значения всегда будут меняться и директории тоже меняются, поэтому я бы не хотел к ним привязываться

Comment: https://html5book.ru/hyperlinks-in-html/

Comment: @AlexeyTen по вашему я не знаю что такое гиперссылки? Вопрос заключается в работе с history.pushState(), а не с ссылками.

Comment: Видимо не знаете, раз не понимаете что pushState вычисляет новый адрес точно так же. Читать пункт 2 ссылки выше

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо! Мне изначально требовалось узнать "что pushState вычисляет новый адрес точно так же". Теперь всё встало на свои места